# I can not edit Google Apps Script after the code is complete

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

- *My problem is the editing ability in the google apps script, not the code itself.
  Thanks,*
- **Explanation**
  I can only edit Google Apps Script in a linear way. So for example if I've written a function and then I want to change a variable in it, I can't seem to be able to do that. To only do a minor change I have to completely write the code again line by line. Has happened every time I try to code in Google Apps Script. I also tested with debugger, seems to show no issues. Now, maybe there could be a specific error in this code, but it happens all the time with me, if I have to edit previous written code, I have to write it again step by step.
- **Here's the code in this case:**
  First function works ok. Second function, to display images, I copied a code from stack overflow, and when I want to change column number in it, I can't edit that. just have to change 3 to 10, that's it.

```
    function myFunction() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Data!A1').setValue('=importdata("URL here")')
    }
    function convertToImage() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      var range = sheet.getDataRange(); 
      // I was trying to change this number from 3 to 10, and it doesn't let me.
      var colnum = 3;             // assuming column C; change to another column number
      var cell;
      var values = range.getValues(); 
      for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i][colnum-1]) {
          cell = range.getCell(i+1, colnum);
          cell.setFormula('=image("'+values[i][colnum-1]+'")')
        }
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate further on your statement **_"I was trying to change this number from 3 to 10, and it doesn't let me."_**  To be honest, your question is a little vague & I can't quite grasp what you really mean as I could only speculate. It would be a big help if you can **share sample data** (for replication on our end) & an **expected output** you'd like to have.

Comment: @IrvinJayG. So far what I've got to know is that it's about the comment. Whenever I comment the code with "//" it stops me from editing the variables below. I can still add new code below, but can not change what's written already. It somehow locks it. I use "ctrl+/" to comment the code.

Comment: I was able to replace 3 by 10 without making other change to the code, so I think that there are some missing details or there might be a problem on your environment (web browser, web browser extensions... etc).

Comment: @Cian That's an odd behavior. On my end, I do not experience what you are describing. I agree with **Rubén** that there might be an issue with the browser you're using. Perhaps you could try some quick troubleshooting by trying a different browser. If ever it is still consistent, then you can try capturing a screen recording/video demonstrating the issue and report it at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) with the video attached.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for pointing out the extensions. It was one of my extensions that interfered with the apps script. I disabled it and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code like this and saved it no problem

```
function convertToImage() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive;
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const col = 4;             
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  for (let i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    if (vs[i][col - 1]) {
      rg.getCell(i + 1, col).setFormula('=image("' + vs[i][col - 1] + '")');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper. yeah now here's the thing. I succeeded to change the number too, but only after I deleted the comment written in the same line. You have deleted that comment too, why is it that we have to delete the comment before changing the number?

Comment: I wouldn’t think that it should. But in my case I always delete all the comments because I hate comments